# How can I minimize the ICs in a 24-hour analogue timer circuit to one?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, timer

I have been trying to design an analogue timer circuit. The circuit needs to be on a 24-hour cycle with the ability to drive a LED light panel at settings of 10 hours on, 14 off; and 12 on, 12 off. Analogue because I want to manufacture these at scale eventually and don't want to deal with microcontrollers.

Accuracy and minimizing drift over time are very important so using a crystal oscillator is required. I had come up with a design using a 32.768 kHz crystal oscillator, two 4060's (14 stage counters, 2^14), some AND gates to get the period to 2.40 hours and then a decade 4017 chip to select the hours I need to then drive a NPN MOSFET on for the LEDs

But of course, this is a lot of chips.

I decided to take apart a simple grow light timer and much to my surprise they have a 16 MHz oscillator and only one IC which I assume is a ripple counter, to break that down to a 2.4 hour cycle they would need 16,000,000/8640 (seconds in an hour) = 1.3824X10^11 = 2^37 - they would need a counter diver with 37 stages.

I have gone through a bunch of parts and the highest stage ripple counter I can find is a 14 stage, which is way way too low for a 2.4/24 hour cycle especially with a 16 MHz oscillator.

Attached is the photo.

[image: timer circuit with 16MHZ oscillator]

So how is this possible? Is this a custom chip and if so how would I get one like this? Affectively reducing 5 ICs in my design down to one! Any feedback/thoughts would be amazing. I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: `only one IC which I assume is a ripple counter` ... never assume anything ... the IC is probably a microcontroller

Comment: Ahh interesting, you think it's just a pre-programed microcontroller?  If I was to try and replicate, do you have any recommendations, e.g. a standard arduino controller like ATmega328P ?

Comment: "don't want to deal with microcontrollers." That's like saying "I want to remove this cancer but I don't want to deal with surgeons".

Comment: The only downside I see for a microcontroller would be availability. But for a simple design like this, there are many pin and function compatible alternatives. I'd use a Microchip PIC, but ATmega and ATtiny are also good.

Comment: These days, yes, stuff like that is just done with an little bitty microcontroller.  You won't need much, and it won't need much code.  You'll want to have them purchased pre-programmed, and then they're just a "function generator".  For production up to tens (hundreds?) of thousands a year an 8- or 6-pin PIC or similar is probably cheapest; beyond that you'll want to embark on a journey of discovery into the land of 4-bit micros.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. When I looked at the PCB I saw no programable pin heads, so I assumed it was an off the shelf IC. - But I now realize that it is possible to get preprogramed microcontrollers which would for sure solve this issue and must be what they have done. I'll start looking into a few microcontroller options and see what I can do.

Comment: you will need a real time clock ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=microcontroller+with+rtc&ia=web ...... the reddit hit is interesting read ... https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/n3zoo3/is_there_a_microcontroller_with_a_built_in_rtc/

Comment: There are explicit timer circuits like CD4521 or CD4536.

Answer (score 1):

Your ripple counter chips that you have found do not have the big division ratios that you would like. Why not consider a lower frequency oscillator to drive the input of the chip. Watch crystals could be useful. If great accuracy is not needed then use a RC oscillator which is easy to set up on a basic frequency counter. Another way is to use the AC mains which is 50 or 60 Hz depending where you live. The AC mains can be sampled with a small cheap transformer. The long term accuracy will be very good in most countries.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a hint, I had a similar requirement a few decades ago. There were a couple of simple solutions (although not used at that time with a very precise timing) with standard CMOS ICs.

The parts (still in production today) are

- [CD4541](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4541b.pdf)
- [CD4536](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4536b.pdf)

They both have some quite long programmable ripple timers. They can have their own oscillator, or if the division ratio fits you well you can still use the advice from @Autistic, using the local 50/60Hz.